# Rails 5 ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Model `User` and `Article`.

In Article model relationship defined `belongs_to :user`. In User model relationship defined  `has_many :articles`

when I trigger below query, gives successful result

```
Article.select(:name, :id).where(user_id:"fb157fc-a9353453cb95", name:"first")
```

But when I trigger below query, it gives an error

```
Article.select(:name, :id).where("user_id (?)","1bf4c2fc-35c37e15d4b5")
```

**Error**  `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

But when I trigger below query, it also gives an error

```
Article.select(:name, :id).where("articles.user_id (?)","1bf4c2fc-35c37e15d4b5")
```

**Error** `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably looking for `IN` query
so its syntax is: -

```
user_ids = [1bf4c2fc-35c37e15d4b5,2nd_user_id, 3rd_user_id]
Article.select(:name, :id).where("user_id IN (?)",user_ids)
```

it will make sql-query like this

```
SELECT "articles"."name","articles"."id"  FROM "articles" WHERE (user_id IN (1bf4c2fc-35c37e15d4b5,2nd_user_id, 3rd_user_id))
```

if you are looking query for one `user_id` in where block then its syntax will be: -

```
user_id = 1bf4c2fc-35c37e15d4b5
Article.select(:name, :id).where("user_id = ?",user_id)
```

it will make sql query like this: -

```
SELECT "articles"."name","articles"."id"  FROM "articles" WHERE (user_id =
 "1bf4c2fc-35c37e15d4b5")
```

Hopefully these two above query will make you clear difference between IN with search multiple user_id and for one user_id also.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `=`. Try:

```
Article.select(:name, :id).where("user_id = (?)","1bf4c2fc-35c37e15d4b5")
```

I would have thought you would do something more like:

```
User.find_by(id: "1bf4c2fc-35c37e15d4b5").articles.select(:name, :id)
```

If you don't need the result to be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` containing a collection of `Article` instances, you could do:

```
User.find_by(id: "1bf4c2fc-35c37e15d4b5").articles.pluck(:name, :id)
```

Which will give you an `array` of `arrays`. I believe this is a bit faster because you're not instantiating ActiveRecord objects. But, it all depends on what you're needs are.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for

```
Article.select(:name, :id).where("user_id =?","1bf4c2fc-35c37e15d4b5")
```

Active Record will take the first argument as the conditions string and any additional arguments will replace the question marks (?) in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following which tested

```
@user_id = "fb157fc-a9353453cb95"
@articles = Article.select(:name, :id).where('user_id IN (?)', @user_id)
```

Hope to help